# Pairwise Conditional Averages in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following table. All are to be considered boolean except `days_old` and `SKU` which are to be considered integer

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'SKU': [10,11,12,13,14,15],
    'frozen':[1,0,1,1,1,0],
    'vegetable':[1,1,0,1,1,0],
    'microwaveable':[1,0,0,0,0,1],
    'days_old':[21,9,11,2,6,14],
})
```

I want a co-occurence table of counts that match both the column and index variables and give the average of days_old:

Desired output:

```
AVERAGE DAYS OLD:
          frozen | vegetable | microwaveable 
frozen        10 |       9.6 |           21
vegetable    9.6 |       9.5 |           21
microw...     21 |        21 |         17.5
```

Comment: Can you break down the computation of `9.25`, and `9.6`?

Comment: I think `9.25` is actually `10` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use dot:

```
df2 = df[['frozen','vegetable','microwaveable']]

df2.T.dot(df2.mul(df['days_old'],axis=0)).div(df2.T.dot(df2)).round(2)
```

Output:

```
               frozen  vegetable  microwaveable
frozen          10.00       9.67           21.0
vegetable        9.67       9.50           21.0
microwaveable   21.00      21.00           17.5
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you want the mean of the combinations of columns for which both columns have a 1.

You could rework the DataFrame to multiply each `1` by the `days_old` value and 0s by NaN, then take advantage of [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) that efficiently computes pairwise correlation of pairs of columns. Since `corr` can use a custom function and only considers rows for which both values are non-NaN, let's just compute the mean of either column. `corr` uses `1` as value for self-correlation, so we need to [`fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) with the mean of each column:

```
tmp = (df.drop(columns=['SKU', 'days_old'])
         .mul(df['days_old'], axis=0)
         .replace(0, np.nan)
      )

# get rid of rows with NaN, compute mean
out = tmp.corr(lambda a,b: a.mean())

# replace diagonal of 1s by the mean of the columns
np.fill_diagonal(out.values, tmp.mean())
```

Less efficient alternative with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

cols = df.columns.difference(['SKU', 'days_old'])

tmp = (df[cols]
         .mul(df['days_old'], axis=0)
         .replace(0, np.nan)
      )

out = (pd.Series({(a, b): tmp[a].where(tmp[b].notna()).mean()
                 for a,b in product(cols, repeat=2)})
         .unstack().reindex(index=cols, columns=cols)
      )
```

Output:

```
                  frozen  vegetable  microwaveable
frozen         10.000000   9.666667           21.0
vegetable       9.666667   9.500000           21.0
microwaveable  21.000000  21.000000           17.5
```

Intermediate `tmp`:

```
   frozen  microwaveable  vegetable
0    21.0           21.0       21.0
1     NaN            NaN        9.0
2    11.0            NaN        NaN
3     2.0            NaN        2.0
4     6.0            NaN        6.0
5     NaN           14.0        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, without multiplying first the dataframe:

```py
from itertools import product

out = pd.Series(
    {
        (a, b): df.loc[df[a].astype(bool) & df[b].astype(bool), "days_old"].mean()
        for a, b in product(df.columns[1:-1], df.columns[1:-1])
    },
).unstack(1)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                  frozen  microwaveable  vegetable
frozen         10.000000           21.0   9.666667
microwaveable  21.000000           17.5  21.000000
vegetable       9.666667           21.0   9.500000
```